# Inconsistently getting 'FirebaseError: Response is not valid JSON object.'

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, expo

I'm working on a react-native app with spotify integration. I've set up the oAuth flow w/ auth code grant where I can get the authorization code. I've then set up cloud function on firebase to proxy the actual token exchange (I don't want to reveal my secret to the client!). I've added logs and can see that the function is correctly completing the exchange with the spotify token endpoint, and receiving a refresh and access token.

```
const tokenRequeset = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

      // spotify network request, error handling, etc here ....

      // I want to emphasize that this network request completes 
      // properly - my log statement below verifies in server logs
      // that I'm getting the expected value.
      const resp = await axios.post(
          "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
          QueryString.stringify({
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            code: code,
            redirect_uri: redirectURI,
          }),
          {
            headers: {
              "Authorization": `Basic ${BEARER_TOKEN}`,
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
          }
      );

      console.log(resp.data.access_token); 
      return { status: "success", token: resp.data.access_token };
});

export default tokenRequest
```

`resp.data.access_token` is the JWT access token used to hit the spotify API - it's a string value [according to the API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/). (I'd provide an example one, but it is an auth token)

However, when I try to use the `firebase/functions` package to call my function from my app, I will sometimes get a 'FirebaseError: Response is not valid JSON object.'

What makes this extra fun is that it's inconsistent - yesterday I had the issue, and then it went away (without changing my code!). I was able to hit both the local emulator function and then the deployed function no problem, but today the 'FirebaseError: Response is not valid JSON object.' error is back.

I have checked the logs for the failed invocations both locally and on the deployed function, and in both cases the spotify API call is working - I'm getting all the expected behavior right up until the return (which isn't working for some reason).

On the client side, I'm configuring firebase like so:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  // Shhhhhh
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const functions = getFunctions(app);
// Uncomment to run locally
connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);

export { app, functions };
```

And then exposing and calling it like so:

```
const SpotifyAuth = httpsCallable(functions, "spotify-auth");

const resp = await SpotifyAuth(code, redirectURI)
```

(I know this isn't full code - I grabbed the relevant portions. Happy to provide more if needed).

I tried looking up this error, and I found results from ~2018/2020 with the old style of firebase/functions, but they seem to be related to region and I'm deployed in the default us-central1 - according to the [SDK documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that means I shouldn't touch it.

The existing solutions to the problem also seem to be based on the old style of function calls, rather than the more recent `httpsCallable()` and `getFunctions(app)`.

I'm going insane trying to figure out why sometimes I'm getting this error

EDIT:

More information on the error - I ran my code again today and didn't see the error locally, but I DID see it when I hit the deployed function.
[image: Screenshot of error message + stack trace in console.]

Again, I want to emphasize that I think the error is in the firebase network response - if you look at the network request I receive a 200 but the response is empty.

[image: Screenshot of network request]

Did an additional full mockup of a function to see what would happen:

```
const test = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log("function call");
  return { status: "success", token: "asdfasdfasdfasdfasfs" };
});

export default test;
```

I'm getting the same error.

UPDATE:
I've given up on using the sdk and `onCall` method for firebase cloud functions - all of my testing thus far indicates that this is a bug or error on the google cloud function side, and there's nothing I can do from my side.

The good news is the `onRequest` approach seems to not have this issue - it's behaving properly and reliably.

I really hope that I've messed up along the way and there's a solution I've missed - the SDK seems fantastic and I like the integration it (is supposed to) offer, but as far as I'm aware right now unless there's a bug fix (or update to the documentation if I'm doing something wrong) it seems like it simply won't work.

I'm still planning on using firebase, but from my experience thus far I'd advise anyone early in their server work to consider using another offering (at least if you need to use the functions - I was able to get storage working).

Comment: Please edit the question to show the exact value of `resp.data.access_token`.  What are you expecting to receive in your app if it calls your function?

Comment: Got it - I'm receiving a string value from the spotify API that I'm passing back to my function. On a successful response from my function, I would expect to see in the 'data' field: `{ status: "success", token: "string value for access_token here"}`.

Again, when the function works and I don't get the error I get a properly formatted response with the `token` value being the proper string.

Comment: What is the value when the function doesn't work?

Comment: @Royalelk you could answer your own question with the solution so we can mark it as the preferred one.

Comment: When the function doesn't work, the logged supposed return value (`console.log(resp.data.access_token)`) shows the proper string that I would expect to see. Again, as far as I'm aware the network request to spotify is working on function side - just something about the return value is failing. I've also tried logging `{ status: "success", token: resp.data.access_token}` to see if for some reason the object got malformed / weird, but it would always produce the return value I would expect to see / wanted.

When I inspect the failing network request the 'response' is just empty.

Comment: @dantebarba when I get a solution I'll make sure to add an edit!

... just nothing is working....

Comment: @Royalelk Sorry I misunderstood you, thought you reached a solution. Have you tried mocking the function with a successful response? Is "const tokenRequeset = functions.https.onCall" the firebase function? You should show us a little bit more of the code in the firebase function to determine why the response is empty.

Comment: That is the firebase function - it gets uploaded to firebase with the function name `spotify-auth`. Do you mean mocking on the client or server side?

I've returned a hardcoded string before from the function and I've seen the same error (server side mocking). But the error happens in the network request so I'm confused as to how I would mock client-side.

Again - I am logging the value of `resp.data.access_token` on the function and I can verify it's getting a proper value from my network request earlier in the function.

Comment: @dantebarba I added more of the code - basically just an axios request I had skipped over. 

I also have some try / catches  and error handling I didn't include for brevity, but the `console.log` statement I included verifies that the correct path is being taken, the network request is being hit, and the network response from spotify is correct.

Comment: @DougStevenson I watched your video on [async/await](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jr7pDZ1RAUg) and I'm pretty confident all my code is correct (although you wrote it for onRequest and not onCall - I don't know if those have different behavior, although I would be shocked if they did).

Comment: @Royalelk yes I was talking about the server-side function. I see you've mocked it and the error continues to randomly pop-up is that correct? Then the most probable cause is some kind of race condition that is happening when calling the function. Also a stacktrace from the error log would be useful too.

Comment: @dantebarba I've attached a screenshot of the client side stack trace and the network request in question. Server side I don't see any errors - just my log statement printing out the correct / expected code received from spotify.

My gut instinct says race condition too - but as I mentioned above I follow the async / await pattern outlined in DougStevenson 's video, and the only promise I wait is that network request to spotify (nothing tricky like a firestore --> AI --> network request or something).

I'm going absolutely insane here - I don't know why it decided to work locally today..